# Error when echo $_GET["jsoncallback"] add code javascript below

Tags: php, javascript, json

I am using code index.php

```
<?php
$str = "<div><ul><li><a href="#">click here</a><ul><li></li></ul></li></ul></div>";
echo $_GET["jsoncallback"] . '(' . json_encode($str) . ');';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav > li > a').click(function() {
        if($(this).attr('class') != 'active') {
            $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
            $(this).next().slideToggle();
            $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

if I using code

```
<?php
    $str = "<div><ul><li><a href="#">click here</a><ul><li></li></ul></li></ul></div>";
    echo $_GET["jsoncallback"] . '(' . json_encode($str) . ');';
    ?>
```

when run index.php is ok,
But when add a javascript below echo line is error: 
missing } in XML expression
[Break On This Error] });

Comment: What's in `$_GET['jsoncallback']` val? Why output a json-encoded snippet of html?

Comment: Don't you have to escape the double-quotes embedded within the string you are assigning to the `$str` variable?

Comment: Indeed, if you're using any proper IDE or editing tool, it should light up like it's already christmas. Even SO spots this error right away.

Answer (score 1):

this line:

```
$$str = "<div><ul><li><a href="#">click here</a><ul><li></li></ul></li></ul></div>";
```

should be like this:

```
$str = "<div><ul><li><a href='#'>click here</a><ul><li></li></ul></li></ul></div>";
```